# golang + grpc: register a service on GrpcServer

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm working with this [example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/examples/helloworld/helloworld) for building a go lang grpc server.

But it seems that I'm missing something - In the example there is a phase of registering a service to the grpc-server but my protoc output has no registration method exported:

```
s := grpc.NewServer()
pb.RegisterGreeterServer(s, &server{})
```

Was there a change in the compilation of protobuf3 files?

Am I'm compiling it in the wrong way?

`protoc --go_output=. *.proto`

And how can I make the service work for the server, It is currently not:

```
func main() {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }
    s := grpc.NewServer()
    //register should go here?!
    reflection.Register(s)
    if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to server: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: afaik for Go grpc you must compile it with plugin
`protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc:. *.proto`

https://github.com/golang/protobuf#grpc-support

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Am I'm compiling it in the wrong way?
>
> `protoc --go_output=. *.proto`

Yes. As pointed out in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42040951/golang-grpc-register-a-service-on-grpcserver#comment71257441_42040951) by [Wendy Adi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1750407/wendy-adi), the command-line option to `protoc` should be `--go_out` not `--go_output` and the `plugins=grpc` option is needed as well (as per the [`codegen.sh` script](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/codegen.sh)). You should be able to use `protoc` to regenerate the `.pb.go` file in the helloworld example:

```
cd $GOPATH/src/google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld
mv helloworld.pb.go helloworld.pb.go.orig
protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc:. helloworld.proto
```

The `greeter_server` should compile correctly afterwards:

```
cd ../greeter_server
go build .
```

Answer (score 0):

if using grpc 3  use below cmd

```
protoc -I=proto --go_out=. --go-grpc_out=. proto/*.proto
```